# How can I install TLS/SSL for python to install Python 3.11 and pip on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I've been fighting this for three days now, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've got a headless raspberry pi 4 and I understand there is no apt package available for python on the raspberry pi, so I need to compile it from source. I've tried following the instructions from three different places that all boil down to

1. wget a bunch of libraries that are prerequisites
2. wget the python version tgz
3. unpack the tgz
4. compile the program
5. profit

Here's the link to one of the instructions I followed with the complete bash script to do this shown below

https://gist.github.com/ersingencturk/768416c4a4a1e32de992460cf40ce839

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ true ]; then
  # get a current python3
  
  sudo apt-get install wget build-essential libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev -y
  VERSION=3.11.1
  VERSION_SHORT=3.11
  
  mkdir -p tmp
  cd tmp
  
  if [ ! -f Python-${VERSION}.tgz ]; then
    wget -O Python-${VERSION}.tgz https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${VERSION}/Python-${VERSION}.tgz
  fi
  
  tar xzf Python-${VERSION}.tgz
  cd Python-${VERSION}
  if [ ! -f python ]; then
    ./configure --enable-optimizations
  fi
  echo "### make altinstall"
  sudo make altinstall
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python${VERSION_SHORT} 1
  
  echo "### install pip"
  /usr/local/bin/python${VERSION_SHORT} -m pip install --upgrade pip
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/local/bin/pip${VERSION_SHORT} 1
  
  cd ..
fi
```

The problem is once everything is installed I'm unable to install anything from pip. When I try I get the error:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

Everything I've found seems to make sure the prerequisites are installed first. What prerequisite am I missing? Is there a way to install ssh without pip or something to get around this problem?

Comment: Nothing in your question seems to actually be about SSH — is your problem that SSL isn't available? Those are different. And it's important to _not_ have Python built and installed before you have the prerequisites installed from apt.

Comment: Oh nuts. Thank you for pointing that out. I meant SSL rather than SSH. Also, yes, I recognize I need the prerequisites installed _before_ I build and install python. I assumed the "libssl-dev" was installing ssl as one of the prerequisites. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, the development header package [does depend on the shared libraries](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libssl-dev) (assuming the Raspbian .deb packaging is correct — you can always check with `apt show libssl-dev` under `Depends` in the output). If you've completely uninstalled Python (including pip) between attempts and have all the prerequisites that are in that shell script, I don't have any other ideas, just wanted to clarify what the question was about :)

Comment: when I try to apt-get install libssl-dev it shows 1.1.01-1~deb9u6.

Comment: Ah. See [this PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0644/#openssl-1-1-0). You'll likely need a newer version of libssl. It looks like it [1.1.1 and 3.0.8 are available](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openssl/), so you may need to `sudo apt-get update` to ensure you're getting the latest package list, or possibly upgrade your distro if you're on an older version like Stretch.